# First story of aliens pretending to be humans especially a "human" family (like Coneheads) that is trying to fit in, maybe for a long time?

Tags: aliens, history-of

My sense is that this is a fairly new (like post 1940s) idea because aliens (on Earth -- Lunarians is very old) themselves are fairly new, but I am not sure.

I think while The Invasion of the Bodysnatchers is an example, I think there is probably an earlier one. And in Bodysnatchers, they do not really pretend, barely at all -- they soon are very open about their goals and being aliens -- they think that there is nothing humans can do which probably would be true in real life.

The alien family theme, maybe here to observe or as scouts for an invasion, or wanting to return home, has become I think a cliche, but at one point it was not.

Comment: [Zenna Henderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenna_Henderson#Works)'s stories about The People come to mind.

Comment: @DoscoJones:This was 1950s, interesting if she wrote the first such stories -- what a rich source of ideas the basic premise is. I can't think of a movie (I know scfi movies better than scifi books) before that and aliens tended to be hostile, which was the basis of the movie's conflict -- if the aliens are good guys but being persecuted that is probably too subtle for many movie producers.

Comment: I feel like there's bound to be an Asimov work about this, although the one that comes to mind, involving sugar people, does not designate them as aliens, just _different_.

Comment: Just before Henderson's first *People* story (1952) is Mack Reynolds' "I'm a Stranger, Myself" (*Thrilling Wonder Stories*, 1951) - note, not the 1960 story "I'm a Stranger Here, Myself" - where a disguised Martian meets a farmer who turns out to be a disguised Venusian.  Would that count?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Probably "Does a Bee Care?" (*If*, June 1957).

Comment: I guess Clark Kent doesn't count because he's just one alien and not scouting for an invasion? Bradbury's "Mars Is Heaven!" aka "The Third Expedition" features hostile aliens masquerading as human families, but maybe it doesn't count because they are on Mars not on Earth. What about Kuttner's 1948 yarn "Don't Look Now", is that an example of what you're looking for? https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_v17n01_1948-03/page/n67/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: @user14111: Clark Kent seems like an early example. Perhaps also the first friendly alien to land on Earth? Earlier stories, way earlier, with some friendly aliens, but not on Earth.

Comment: Are you wanting to limit  it to literal extraterrestrial, high tech, aliens?  Not supernatural/mythological?

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile: if u allow myth, it is ancient, like gods pretending to be men. as i think u were getting at. so no.

Answer (score 13):

Not a full family, but Ell, one of the main characters in [Kurd Laßwitz' "Two Planets" from 1897](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Planets) is a half Martian who lives and works unrecognized amongst humans.

His father had been the sole survivor of a Martian expedition force that had landed in the arctic of all places. In the novel, Earthlings and Martians look alike and are biologically compatible, so he made it to civilization, got married and before he perished (from the strain of having to live under Earths higher gravity, if I recall correctly) had a son, who, following his fathers intentions, in turn funded efforts with the secret goal of making contact with the Martians. So that would be an early example of an alien living amongst humans who wanted (but was unable) to go home (and had a life on Earth and a family instead).

Comment: Good old Kurd comes through again. I gotta read that book one of these days. If there is a friendly alien (the father and the half-alien son) earlier I would be surprised. The gravity thing is sophisticated.

Comment: @releseabe When later in the novel the Martians come to earth, they wear big hats with a vacuum bubble on top to create uplift to take some of the strain from the gravity from their necks when they have to move under Earth's gravity (in their own quarters, they have artificial lower gravity), so Laßwitz clearly gave this some thought.

Comment: The vacuum bubble i assume is just a balloon in effect? If so, very big hats. If not, how do they work?

Comment: @releseabe it is a ballon effect, and they are comically big hats, which is remarked upon by the humans in the story  (they target the hats metaphorically in caricature and at some point rather literally, when a human resistance fighter disables a Martian by damaging his hat).

Answer (score 7):

**Zenna Henderson's The People (1952+)**

US writer [Zenna Henderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenna_Henderson) wrote a number of stories about ["The People"](https://www.tor.com/2018/06/07/immigrants-in-an-alien-world-zenna-hendersons-the-people-no-different-flesh/), humanoid beings from a faraway planet who are forced to emigrate to Earth when their home world is destroyed by a natural disaster. They possess various sorts of psionic powers. The first story, "Ararat" is from 1952.

The People are not just one family, but an extended community living undercover.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the Japanese film *Destroy all Monsters* (1968) aliens called the Kilaaks, invade Earth and establish a hidden base near Tokyo. They look like beautiful women, but when exposed to cold temperatures they revert to their true forms, tiny metallic worm like creatures.

https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Kilaak#/media/File:Kilaaks.jpg

In the US tv series *The Invaders* (1967-68) architect David Vincent struggled to expose alien invaders who used technology to "take on human form" and infiltrate Earth institutions.  I am uncertain whether the true alien form of any invader was ever shown.

*The Outer Limits* (1963-1965) had an episode "The Children of Spider County" (February 17, 1964).  A nonhuman looking alien comes to Earth to find his five grown and human looking sons he fathered with Earth women. So the half human sons had been living as humans in rural Spider County for the first parts of their lives.

In the US film *The Day Mars Invaded Earth* (1962) Martians seek to kill a scientist and his family and replace them with duplicates to help them take over Earth.

In the British film  *The Village of the Damned* (1960) based on John Wyndham's *The Midwich Cuckoos* (1957) everyone in the village of Midwich falls unconscious for several hours.  Months later, human appearing children are born in the village, who live with their human mothers.  But it is suspected that they are actually aliens with the mission of conquering Earth.

*Invasion of the Body Snatchers* (1956) based on Jack Finney's 1954 novel *The Body Snatchers* has strange pods appear on Earth.  Each pod grows a duplicate of a nearby person.  When the duplicate in the body is completed, the person dies and the duplicate takes their place.

In *this Island Earth* (1955), based on the 1952 novel of the same name by Raymond F. Jones, (in turned based on his stories from *Thrilling Wonder Stories* 1949-1950) scientists at a mysterious  research institute notice that the staff have rather unusual appearances.  But it takes them a while to learn the staff are from the planet Metaluna.

In *It Came From Outer Space* (1953) highly nonhuman aliens crash on Earth. They abduct some local humans and send aliens shapeshifted into the appearance of those humans to gather the supplies they need to repair their ship.

E.E. Smith's *Lensman* series was first published in *Astounding* on and off from September 1937 to February 1948. They were then revised and published in hardback book form from 1950 to 1954.  Smith's earlier novel *Triplanetary* (*Amazing Stories)* 1934, was extensively rewritten to make it part of the *Lensman* series and published as a book in 1948, and a new novel, *First Lensman* was written, and published in 1950.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman_series

In the revised version in the books from 1948 to 1954, the super powerful aliens, the Arisians and the Eddorians, could "energize forms of flesh" (much like the ainur in Tolkien's legendarium) to impersonate members of lesser species and influence their development.  I don not remember any time groups of Arisians or Eddorians masqueraded as a human family.

I note that one Eddorian, Gharlane, was several notorious human leaders (including at least one case of leaders with overlapping lifetimes) from history.  Some of those leaders had apparently human wives and children, who might have been real humans or Eddorians disguised as humans.

*The Thing From Another World* (1951), and various remakes are based on Don A. Stuart's (John W. Campbells') "Who Goes There?" *Astounding Science Fiction* (1938).

In "Who Goes There?" a shapeshifting alien is found on Earth. It can imitate any life form perfectly, and any tiny part of it which is detached becomes a separate shapeshifting alien.

in Stanley G. Weinbaum's short story "A Martian Odyssey", (*Wonder Stories*, July 1934) protagonist Dick Jarvis, crossing the desert Xanthus on the planet Mars, sees Fancy Long, a woman he knows from the cast of the *Yerba Mate Hour* show in New York City. But she is really an illusion created by a Martian creature.  This is similar but not identical to the question.

The famous *Buck Rogers* (19219*-1967) w2as based on Philip Nolan's *Armageddon 2419 AD*, *Amazing Stories* (August 1928).  The plot of *Armageddon 2419 AD* features an American revolt against the Chinese conquerors.  And as Ir3emember from a paperback edition in the 1960s, a large meteorite or possibly a spaceship had crashed in China centuries earlier, and it was suspected that the new type of Chinese people who conquered the USA may have been mutants caused by the crash or aliens from another world.

And I feel like I am forgetting some important stories with the plot of aliens impersonating humans.

Comment: Interesting collection (I like the first movie about metallic worms and it reminds me of someone I used to know). The incredibly racist but interesting idea that Chinese may be mutants and the meteorite -- there was that Matt Damon monster movie from China that I wonder if was inspired by Buck Rogers although meteors harboring life or being spaceships is not so new.  I think once the theme was introduced, it really caught on so anything exhaustive after 1960 would list probably dozens of films and stories.

Comment: The Thing does not really belong (not the movies). I guess as in the case of the doctor pretending to be human qualifies but it is a very short-term arrangement. Certainly the 1950s movie does not qualify at all. The written story I have forgotten.

Comment: @releseabe The written novel, ["Who Goes There"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Goes_There%3F) is by John Campbell and was published in 1938. It seems to meet the criteria of the question.

Comment: @Wastrel: Yes, it is an alien pretending to be a human but I had in mind a more long-term thing, I mention fitting in which is protracted, not pretending to be human just long enough to kill or infect real humans.